# Conversion function for 3D value into 2D in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I have written a function for converting 3D values into 2D, but not able to get it working may be I am parsing the wrong values.

I am passing the value in the `valuse` as 2 coordinates and trying to get into `Output` in 2D. Can anyone please do the correction in the function below and help me in running the function?

```
% Perspective Projection
function Output = perspective_projection(Input)
 Output = zeros(size(Input));
 for ii = 1: length(Input)
  Output(ii,1) = Input(ii,1)/Input(ii,3);
  Output(ii,2)=Input(ii,2)/Input(ii,3);
 end


value = [6,4,2];
[a1,b1] = perspective_projection(a1)
```

Comment: Try this - "for i = 1: size(Input,1)".

Comment: @Divakar It didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should rewrite your function as:

```
function Output = perspective_projection(Input)
    Output = bsxfun(@rdivide, Input(:,1:2), Input(:,3)); 
end
```

or, judging from the way you seem to be calling it:

```
function [OutputX,OutputY] = perspective_projection(Input)
    OutputX = Input(:,1)./Input(:,3); 
    OutputY = Input(:,2)./Input(:,3); 
end
```

Note that your function is quite simple (I wouldn't even use a function):

```
[X,Y] = deal(Input(:,1)./Input(:,3), Input(:,2)./Input(:,3));
```

As for your original function: the error is in the initialization:

```
function Output = perspective_projection(Input)

    %// WRONG: this initializes a 3D array!
    Output = zeros(size(Input));

    %// ...but you want a 2D array
    for ii = 1: length(Input)
        Output(ii,1) = Input(ii,1)/Input(ii,3);
        Output(ii,2) = Input(ii,2)/Input(ii,3);
    end

end
```

and of course, the multiple outputs (but it's not quite clear to me whether you want that or not...)

Comment: Yeah I am trying as according the way I called it. I want to convert 3D cordinates(x,y,z) into 2D (x/z,y/z). Now it seems its almost done. Thanks a lot, You made my day :)

Comment: Will second function you have written give same values? Hot to call that? Thanks

Comment: @ParveenArora: Example: `[X,Y] = perspective_projection(coordinates)` where `coordinates` is an N×3 matrix. `X` and `Y` are then N×1 vectors.

Comment: I am trying to use it like 
[X,Y] = perspective_projection(6,4,2);
But its not working, I know this is silly thing to ask, but can you please clarify. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ParveenArora: Use `[X,Y] = perspective_projection([6,4,2]);`

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot. I just bought you a coffee :D

Answer (score 3):

BSXFUN method as suggested by Rody is an elegant way, but if you would like to keep your loop, try this -

```
% Perspective Projection
function Output = perspective_projection(Input)
Output = zeros(size(Input,1),2);
for ii = 1: size(Input,1)
    Output(ii,1) = Input(ii,1)/Input(ii,3);
    Output(ii,2) = Input(ii,2)/Input(ii,3);
end
```

Comment: +1, but the `size(Input,2)` is not really needed; it should just be `2`.

Comment: How to call this function with values?

Comment: Using random numbers - "a1 = rand(2,3,4); Output = perspective_projection(a1)".